# Receive JSON in python Bottle

Tags: python, json, bottle

I am trying to do a JSON post to my Bottle server.

```
from bottle import request, route, run
@route('/feedback', method='POST')
def feedback():
    data = request.json
    print data

run(host='localhost',port=8080)
```

In the client side, I have

```
$('#user_feedback').submit(function() {
  var feedback = {"id": 1}
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://localhost:8080/feedback",
     data: feedback
 });
 return false;
});
```

I am returning false here because I don't want the page to be redirected.

However, the `data` I received in my Bottle server is always `None` when printed out. 
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.json` expects the content type of the request to be `application/json` .
So to make it work, you should set the `contentType` property of your request to `application/json` and stringify your data :

```
$.ajax({ 
    type:"POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url:"/feedback",
    data: JSON.stringify(feedback)
});
```

Comment: what if i want to send "application/x-www-form-urlencoded JSON string"